# Overflow:hidden can't scroll in div

Tags: html, css

I can't scroll vertical in the div when I set overflow:hidden to it. 
I don't understand why.

HTML:

```
<div class="s">
<p>lorem ispum<br/></p>
<p>lorem ispum<br/></p>
<p>lorem ispum<br/></p>
<p>lorem ispum<br/></p>
<p>lorem ispum<br/></p>
<p>lorem ispum<br/></p>
<p>lorem ispum<br/></p>
<p>lorem ispum<br/></p>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .s{
        overflow:hidden;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    body{
        height:100%;
    }
```

I make a test JsFiddle to show the error.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccrhpbp5/)

**Update:**

I need to hide the scrollbar, but i can't scroll if it's hidden.

Comment: set to .s overflow:scroll; to make it scrollable

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to do. 
Change to `overflow:auto` instead

Comment: use  .s{overflow-y:scroll;} . try it

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to hide the scroll bar but you wish to let it scroll, you can have a container with `overflow:hidden;` and a child container with `overflow-y:scroll`, and hide the scroll bar with negative right margin.

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5gjabvx/)

The CSS :

```
.cont{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.s{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:-30px;
}
```

The HTML :

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="s">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
.s {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

.s::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

One for firefox and other for chrome

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `overflow: hdden` with `overflow-x: hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you mean vertical or not, but if you want to be able to scroll horizontally but vertically hidden, change it to:

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

likewise if you want to be the other way around, change to:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the overflow property of the containing `<div class='s'>` to hidden.  As the name suggests, this will hide any containing content that spills out of the `<div>` dimensions.

Try setting:

```
.s{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccrhpbp5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be:

1. put `overflow:hidden` to container
2. `document.getElementbyId().scroll = true`
3. Then you can do scroll

Comment: There's lots of help available in the [help], including [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Why not start off with the [tour]?

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped my entire content inside the body in a div. And then in the `content` class in CSS, I gave max-height and hid the scrollbar.

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- My actual content -->
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
.content {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
}
```

For me, the `max-height` element was the key attribute.